# How to count the number of following rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe below

```
A B
1 a0
2 b0
3 b1
4 a1
5 b2
6 a2
```

First,I would like to cut `df`.with startswith("a")

df1

```
A B
1 a0
2 b0
3 b1
```

df2

```
A B
4 a1
5 b2
```

df3

```
A B
6 a2
```

And I would like to count the rows.
And summarize the result.

My desired result is below

```
   rows 
a0 3
a1 2
a2 1
```

How this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert cells not starting with `a` to missing values and forward fill the series and then do `value_counts`:

```
df.B.where(df.B.str.startswith("a"), None).ffill().value_counts()
​
#a0    3
#a1    2
#a2    1
#Name: B, dtype: int64
```

---

If you have duplicated `a`s appear, to differentiate them, you can create an additional group variable with `cumsum`:

```
start_a = df.B.str.startswith("a")
df.groupby(by = [df.B.where(start_a, None).ffill(), start_a.cumsum().rename('g')]).size()

#B   g        # here is an extra group variable to differentiate possible duplicated a rows
#a0  1    3
#a1  2    2
#a2  3    1
#dtype: int64
```