# How to count the following number of rows in pandas (new)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Relate to the question below,I would like to count the number of following rows.
Thanks to the answer,I could handle data.

But I met some trouble and exception.

[How to count the number of following rows in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41971457/how-to-count-the-number-of-following-rows-in-pandas)

```
A B
1 a0
2 a1
3 b1
4 a0
5 b2
6 a2
7 a2
```

First,I would like to cut df.with startswith("a")

df1

```
A B
1 a0
```

df2

```
A B
2 a1
3 b1
```

df3

```
A B
4 a0
5 b2
```

df4

```
A B
6 a2
```

df5

```
A B
7 a2
```

I would like to count each df's rows

```
"a"  number
a0  1
a1  2
a0  2
a2  1
a2  1
```

How could be this done?

I am happy someone tell me how to handle this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) by custom `Series` created with `cumsum`:

```
print (df.B.str.startswith("a").cumsum())
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    4
6    5
Name: B, dtype: int32

df1 = df.B.groupby(df.B.str.startswith("a").cumsum()).agg(['first', 'size'])
df1.columns =['"A"','number']
df1.index.name = None
print (df1)
  "A"  number
1  a0       1
2  a1       2
3  a0       2
4  a2       1
5  a2       1
```